# remove objectAtIndex behaving strangely

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

hi I have an array of array and I'm removing an object at a certain index after Im adding it. somehow I think this is behaving strangely or I may have overlooked something. here's the code. I sprinkled it with nslogs for tracing.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < easyQuestionsLength; i++) {
    NSMutableArray *questionSet = [easyQuestions objectAtIndex:i];
    for(int j = 0; j < [[easyQuestionsVariant objectAtIndex:i] count]; j++)
    {
        NSArray *variant = [[easyQuestionsVariant objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j];
        NSLog(@"questionSet b4 %@",questionSet);

        [questionSet insertObject:variant atIndex:7];
        NSLog(@"questionSet aft ins%@",questionSet);

        [questionsArray addObject:questionSet];
        NSLog(@"questionsArray aft add %@",questionsArray);

        [questionSet removeObjectAtIndex:7];
        NSLog(@"questionsArray aft rem %@",questionsArray);

        easyQCtr++;
    }
}
```

here's the debug console output:

```
2011-09-06 16:17:33.498 EasyQuiz[25584:10d03] questionSet b4 (
0,
1,
14,
"[1] The value of the digit {#} in {#} is __________.",
none,
2,
1
)
2011-09-06 16:17:33.499 EasyQuiz[25584:10d03] questionSet aft (
0,
1,
14,
"[1] The value of the digit {#} in {#} is __________.",
none,
2,
1,
    {
    choice =         (
        70000,
        7000,
        700,
        70
    );
    var =         (
        7,
        70348
    );
}
)
2011-09-06 16:17:33.500 EasyQuiz[25584:10d03] questionsArray aft add (
    (
    0,
    1,
    14,
    "[1] The value of the digit {#} in {#} is __________.",
    none,
    2,
    1,
            {
        choice =             (
            70000,
            7000,
            700,
            70
        );
        var =             (
            7,
            70348
        );
    }
)
)
2011-09-06 16:17:33.500 EasyQuiz[25584:10d03] questionsArray aft rem (
    (
    0,
    1,
    14,
    "[1] The value of the digit {#} in {#} is __________.",
    none,
    2,
    1
)
)
```

I'm only doing a removeObjectAtIndex here [questionSet removeObjectAtIndex:7]; but why is also removing from questionsArray? I'm completely lost here. I know this is logic error but I can't seem to find the problem. :D

Comment: Where you are creating `questionsArray`?

Comment: I create questionsArray just outside the loop like this. 
questionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    int easyQCtr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < easyQuestionsLength; i++) {
    ...

Comment: Ok. Your code seems to be bit confusing. Can you explain what exactly you are doing with `questionsArray`  and `questionSet`?

Comment: yeah I know its confusing. :D anyway, questionArray will hold the final output of questionSet which will look like the one in my nslog that says "questionsArray aft add". questionSet is only one question and questionArray will be the collection of all questionSet until the loop stops.

Comment: It seems `questionsArray aft add` contains different type of objects.

Answer (score 2):

*questionsArray* is an array, and arrays do not **contain** the objects, they only contain **pointers** to the real data. So if you add an item to an array, **no copy is made**, only the pointer to the original object is stored and the object retained.

You added an array object to *questionsArray*, but that is only a new reference. If you wanted to store a copy, you'd have to do:

```
[questionsArray addObject: [questionSet copy]];
```

### Update

FWIW, *questionSet* and *questionsArray* ***do most definitely not point to the same object***. This can be seen in the display you get

*questionSet* displays as

```
(               --> questionSet, containing:
  0,
  1,
  14,
  ...
)
```

while *questionsArray* displays as

```
(               --> questionsArray, containing:
  (             --> questionSet (only element of questionsArray), containing:
    0,
    1,
    14,
    ...
  )
)
```

This shows that *questionsArray* contains one object, *questionSet*. The fact you can remove something from *questionSet* and it displays in *questionsArray*, and vice versa is explained by the fact that *questionsArray* only contains a ***reference to*** and ***not a copy of*** *questionSet*, and that description recursively displays all elements of contained arrays, sets, and dictionaries.

Take a look at this simple code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *deeplyNested = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
    NSArray *toplevel = [NSArray arrayWithObject: [NSArray arrayWithObject: deeplyNested]];

    NSLog(@"\n%@", toplevel);

    [[[toplevel lastObject] lastObject] removeObjectAtIndex: 1];
    [deeplyNested addObject: @"thousand"];

    NSLog(@"\n%@", toplevel);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
2011-09-06 12:36:44.966 NestedArrays[12553:707] 
(
    (
        (
            one,
            two,
            three
        )
    )
)
2011-09-06 12:36:44.968 NestedArrays[12553:707] 
(
    (
        (
            one,
            three,
            thousand
        )
    )
)
```

As you can see, *deeplyNested* can be addressed through `[[toplevel lastObject] lastObject]`, or directly. The result is the same, as they reference the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that questionsArray is a pointer to questionSet and not a distinct actual array in it's own right. Or vice versa. Make sure you create using copy:

```
NSMutableArray *questionSet = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[easyQuestions objectAtIndex:i] copyItems:YES];
```

Comment: I don't think so. questionsArray is a separate array, containing **references to**, and not **copies of** other arrays (in this case, only one).